# No mapping exists from object type Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry to a known managed provider native type

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, spatial

I have a tool I wrote to import shapefile data to our database. It uses EntityFramework 6.1.3 and .NET 4.5.

It works great however when I move the same code into our existing web application to seed the database at startup it fails with:

"No mapping exists from object type Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry to a known managed provider native type."

The web application is also using EF 6.1.3 and .NET 4.5. Packages are managed with NuGet. We are loading the shapefiles using the DotSpatial libraries.

I am using DbGeometry defined in System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

```
foreach (IFeature feature in sf.Features)
{
    var wkt = feature.ToShape().ToGeometry().ToString();
    AdminDistrict ad = new AdminDistrict()
    {
        Id = Convert.ToInt64(feature.DataRow[fieldMap["Id"]]),
        ShortName = feature.DataRow[fieldMap["ShortName"]].ToString(),
        LongName = feature.DataRow[fieldMap["LongName"]].ToString(),
        Type = config.Type,
        Country = config.Country,
        Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow,
        Geom = DbGeometry.FromText(wkt, 4326)
    };

    db.AdminDistricts.Add(ad);

}
db.SaveChanges();  //Exception is here...
```

I am going to  create 'new' web application project and try the same thing, will provide results when I have them.

Comment: Obviously I must have some conflicting version references somewhere impacting EF. It works fine on a new web application project.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server Spatial types on a machine without SQL Server installed, you will need to include the following NuGet package with your project.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types

Allows you to use SQL Server spatial types on a machine without SQL Server installed. Useful when deploying to Windows Azure. Also enables Entity Framework spatial types to be used (DbGeography and DbGeometry).

Comment: SQL Server is currently installed on the same machine. The original tool works as expected, code was simply moved over into the web app code base.

Answer (score 0):

Found some older library references causing System.Data v2.0.0.0 to be loaded. I added a new assemblyBinding to make sure it to loads v4.0

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```